# Jquery and id is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I use the function load for call other page inside other , and i see break all my other codes , in firebug tell me that , id is not defined

**My script it´s this :**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {



jQuery("#web_perfiles_col_3").load(""+dir_load_footer_users_on);        


var auto_refresh = setInterval(

function ()
{   

var randnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*999999999999);

jQuery("#web_perfiles_col_3").load(""+dir_load_footer_users_on+"&rand_n="+randnumber);  

},2000);


});
```

**This script break all my other codes , the problem come from the this line :**

```
 jQuery("#web_perfiles_col_3").load(""+dir_load_footer_users_on);
```

I try also using without "" double and single quotes but the problem continue , the case it´s this script it´s inside file with other scripts and in some page this var "dir_load_footer_users_on" no have value , if i delete this line works but it´s the first time i see this problem i don´t know this thing get error for other script because i no defined one var

For me it´s ridiculous that by no defined one var break other scripts ??? , it´s possible fix this or howewer i writte bad or i must do special thing for all works ???

Thank´s everybody for the help in this case

```
**P.D :** dir_load_footer_users_on it´s one **var**
```

Comment: How are you including the jQuery src?

Comment: what is `dir_load_footer_users_on` defined as?? A variable? An object? An array? A function???

Comment: if `dir_load_footer_users_on` can possibly be undefined, you must write the above code to stop before it tries using it when it is undefined.

Comment: dir_load_footer_users_on it´s defined as var , right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if we knew what `dir_load_footer_users_on` was, but maybe something like this?

```
if(typeof dir_load_footer_users_on != 'undefined') {
    jQuery("#web_perfiles_col_3").load(""+dir_load_footer_users_on);
}
```

Comment: dir_load_footer_users_on it´s var defined in other page , the problem it´s for no defined when the file with scripts load in other page without this var defined

Comment: The code above checks if `dir_load_footer_users_on` is defined, and only runs `jQuery().load()` if it is. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes fix my problem but i don´t know that by no defined var break other codes , it´s possible this ? , regards and my positive go for you , thank´s

Comment: If it didn't break you would never know anything was wrong, and that might cause all kinds of unexplainable trouble later on. Javascript is already very forgiving compared to other languages.